# Fetch data from 4 tables join together using hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

I have 4 tables:

Teacher, Student, Course and their common join table TeacherStudentCourse.

The first three tables all have one to many relationship with the last table.
Here is a screenshot from my DB [DataBase sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ehro.png) 
Hence, for example, I should be able to get the desire Students by providing Teacher ID and Course ID.

I had previously asked a question on join table. [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544479/hibernate-detached-criteria-with-join-table)
And I do get the answer. 
I was trying to improve based on the previous codes

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Object> list = session.createQuery("select s from Student s join s.teacherStudentCourses tsc where tsc.teacher = :teacher and tsc.course = :course")
            .setParameter("teacher", teacher)
            .setParameter("course", course)
            .list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

But I do not seem to get it working after countless tries. Maybe the query just cannot create in that way? Any helps will be appreciated!

[UPDATE]

The error I get is:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: teacherStudentCourses of: model.Student [select s from model.Student s join s.teacherStudentCourses tsc where tsc.teacher = :teacher and tsc.course = :course]

Comment: The error states that Student entity does not have teacherStudentCourses  field properly mapped. If you need more help just post your entities code

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:  search this error on SO there are lots of QA regarding this error. I am sure you will find the answer.
BTW seems like you haven't mapped  teacherStudentCourses in student.

Comment: Hmmm i think i was my mistake, when i coded the teacherStudentCourses filed property in student class, i some how had a double 's' for the teacherStudentCourse**ss**.. now it throws me some other errors, still debugging

Comment: @Joker, I actually do have the mapping, but its not shown in the ERD generated using the reverse engineering in MySQL workbench

Answer (score 0):

Here tables are associated to each other with foreign key so all child table (teacher,cource,student) should have a parent type variable in their POJO.

Let this is "TeacherStudentCource tsc" in Student.class.
Now the query will be..

```
select s.studentId,s.name,s.gender,s.birthdate, from Student s inner join s.tsc b where b.teacherId=:tid and b.courceId=:cid;
```

Teacher ID=tid 
Course ID =cid